# Манипулирование элементами DOM модели с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Всем привет! Как я писал ранее - делаю прототип онлайн конструктора визиток, который можно увидеть по адресу http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html. Также прилагаю изображение страницы сайта к вопросу. Вот, что я хочу сделать: Убрать **"Настройки шрифта"**, но когда пользователь наводит фокус на какое-либо поле формы, слева, под этим полем появляется блок **"Настройки шрифта"**. Когда поле теряет фокус блок **"Настройки шрифта"** исчезает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне лучше всего это реализовать? С помощью jQuery?

На картинке красной рамкой выделен блок **"Настройки шрифта"**, который нужно отображать, при получении полем фокуса, и скрывать при потере фокуса. Только я думал отображать сразу под полем, а как думаете Вы? Использование методов **hide и show** будет достаточно?
[image: Онлайн конструктор визиток]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто прикрутить событие к инпутам при получении фокуса, но обычным show/hide не отделаться, так как исходя из задачи для каждого элемента свой шрифт. Следовательно, можно сделать один блок настроек шрифтов, при получении фокуса любого элемента из левой колонки в соответствии с ним делать разные значения в настройках шрифтов. Иными словами, например поле фамилия name="surname", при получении фокуса отображается #fontsettings, каждое изменение полей в #fontsettings заносится в соответствующий массив типа fontsettings['surname']['fontsize']. После на выходе мы можем получить параметры шрифта для любого поля.

Насчет отображения этих самых настроек шрифта - не очень удачно, не всем пользователям будет понятно, что эти настройки относятся именно к этому полю, может добавить какие-нибудь стрелочки, но размещать прямо под полем тоже не стоит, так как если оно список полей будет постоянно меняться в высоте - не есть хорошо.